# UDP: doubts about write() and socket timeout (SO_SNDTIMEO) when the socket buffer is full

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, timeout, buffer

I'm having some problems understanding how socket buffers and timeouts are managed under Linux, when using UDP. I'm using the OpenWrt embedded Linux distribution, with kernel version 4.14.63.

In order to better understand these concepts, I'm trying to analyze the code that is used by a client of the iPerf open source network measurement program, when sending UDP packets to test parameters such as reachable throughput. It is written in C and C++.

In particular, I tried setting an offered traffic value much higher to what the network (and consequently yhe receiver) can deliver, obtaining as expected a certain packet loss.

In this case, thanks to iPerf computing the loop time after the transmission of each packet, using timestamps, I was able to estimate how much time the application took to write each packet to the UDP buffer.
The packets are actually written inside a while() loop, which calls write() on a socket for each of them.

A timeout is also set, once, on the socket by calling:

```
setsockopt(mSettings->mSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout))
```

This should set a send timeout when writing to the socket, which is, of course, a blocking one.

When the buffer is full, the write() call is blocking and I can see the loop time increasing a lot; the problem is that I can't really understand for how much time this call blocks the application.
In general, when a write() is blocked, does it unblock just as there is room for a new packet? Or does it wait more (as it seems to happen; as far as I was able to understand, trying to set a "big" UDP buffer value (800 KB, when sending UDP datagram with a 1470 B payload), it seems to wait for around 700 ms, letting the buffer get emptied, by the networking stack that is continuosly sending data, for more than the space a single packet would require)? Why?

The other doubt I have is related to the timeout: I tried making little modifications to the source code in order to log the return value of each write() call and I was able to observe that no errors are ever ecountered, even when setting a timeout of 300 ms or 600 ms, which is less than the 700 ms value observed before.

By logging also the evolution of the buffer (together with the loop time at each packet transmission), thanks to ioctl:

```
ioctl(mSettings->mSock,TIOCOUTQ,&bufsize);
```

I was able to observe, however, that setting the timeout to 300 ms or 600 ms actually made the difference, and made the blocking write() wait for around 300 ms, in the first case, or 600 ms, in the second case, as the full buffer is detected.
So, even though no errors are detected, the timeout seems to actually expire; this, however, seems to lead to a correct write operation in all the cases.

Is this possible? Can it happen because the write() blocked the application for enough time to let it completely write the data when the timeout expires?

I'm a bit confused about this.

Thank you very much in advance.